# Please answer faster/quicker/...?

Tags: word-choice

I message her and she takes a long time to answer. I want to ask her to answer my messages not so late. Should I use faster or quicker or ...?

> Please answer my messages faster/quicker/...?

Comment: Who is "she" and why exactly do you need a faster response? Appropriate responses will be very different depending on these answers (e.g. how you text your teenage daughter about letting you know when she will be home at night is very different from how you email your boss asking for approval of a proposal).

Comment: swiftly, promptly, briskly

Comment: If this is a romantic setting, I fear your lack of patience could be your ruin ;) having said that. It depends entirely on the setting you'd need to provide more information. If it was a member of your team (that you are superior too) - "I need a quicker response" would work fine ; In terms of a more general phrase that would work in most circumstances : "please be quicker with your replies" reads well enough, Finally as I say if it's romantic, maybe best to wait!

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602308/2085).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polite way to say it would be something like, "I would appreciate a quick response, if possible" or, "We are working under a tight deadline, and need a response as quickly as possible."

Answer (score 0):

> I would truly appreciate a shorter response time.

Or:

> When it comes to responding to one's messages, promptness can be a virtue.

Or:

> Please respond sooner than usual.

Comment: I would advise against the second option, as it sounds condescending and the third because it is rather aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

In most of email conversation people use

> I would appreciate your prompt reply.

Comment: No they don't.  You can't appreciate something you haven't had yet.  You need to insert the word 'would'.